# Object is only read by multiple threads, does it needs synchronization

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

The collection object that I have is a singleton type, which contains a list of particular object, each index in the list is read by multiple threads, so that they can query an integer property value to be used by a thread local variable. Does this case need any safety using synchronization, in my view No, but posting the question to be doubly sure.

There's no update happening to the object mentioned above on the multiple threads, they are just reading. In my view even ReaderWriterLockSlim needn't be used here, since there's no write. Please confirm my understanding.

Code is something like:

Here NumOfLocs, threadProp are specific to a thread and collection count and objects doesn't change, while threads are reading, they are just fixed in the beginning during initialization

```
int NumOfLocs = collectionObject.LocCollection.Count;

int threadProp = collectionObject.LocCollection[index].Prop
```

Comment: if you just reading (if you will not going to change it while reading )then no need

Comment: So what you do is create this data once when your program is loaded and then just read from this data structure?

Comment: What type `LocCollection` is? FCL collections (located at `System.Collections` and `System.Collections.Generic`) are thread-safe for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't need synchronization if you're only reading the collection. If you wanted to update the collection however, there's a list of Thread-safe collection classes available in System.Collections.Concurrent which you could use. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) for the MSDN documentation.

Comment: This isn't true for *every* collection could be implemented. Of course, this *should be* true.

Answer (score 1):

Usually functions that are meant to read the state do not change the state. But sometimes some function of some object will change some internal object's state, contrary to common sense. This for instance could happen if object is caching something, or rearranging internal structure. It is impossible to tell up front what some object does in any of its functions, without knowing the internal workings of the object.

If it's standard .NET object then there's probably a documentation for it that will tell you if the object is thread safe for reading. If it's some third party object then you have to ask that third party. If you coded the object then only you know.

Comment: Explain the downvotes please. I see nothing wrong with the answer.